# Rails devise plugin customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, change-password

In my current Ruby on Rails project, the devise plugin has been used for authentication. To change the password, I added the devise plugin's passwords/edit.html.erb file into the user directory in my project. Everything's working fine except the error messages are not showing.

This is my current `update_password` method

```
def update_password
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render "edit"  
    end
  end
```

I've mentioned the require validation in the user model as follows

```
validates_presence_of :name, :primary_locale, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation
```

This is my edit form code:

```
<div id="loginForm" class="editPwFormHeight">
    <div id="loginHeader"><h3><%= image_tag("wif_small.png"); %></h3></div>
    <div id="loginContent">
        <%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_password", :locale => params[:locale] }, :method => "post") do |f| %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>
            <p><%= f.password_field :current_password, :class => "login_txt", :placeholder => I18n.t('wi.common.enterCurrentPw'), :autocomplete => "off" %></p>
            <p><%= f.password_field :password, :class => "login_txt", :placeholder => I18n.t('wif.common.newPw'), :autocomplete => "off"  %></p>
            <p><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => "login_txt", :placeholder => I18n.t('wif.common.confirmPw'), :autocomplete => "off" %></p>
            <p>
                <input id="user_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="<%= I18n.t('wif.common.updatePw') %>" class="login_btn" /> 
                <input id="user_cancel" name="commit" type="button" value="<%= I18n.t('wif.common.cancel') %>" class="login_btn" />
            </p>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone can help me to solve this issue. I wanted to show the error message if the user has not typed the current password, or any other error which are currently supporting by the devise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following line to your template:

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

You can customise the messages themselves by editing Devise's translation files, e.g. `config/locales/devise.en.yml`

If you're not using devise's built-in controllers, then you will need to register the [`DeviseHelper`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb) module as a helper in your controller using the [`helper`](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#M000102) method.

Comment: Yes, I added it, but then it says `undefined method devise_error_messages! for #<#<Class:0x593e740>:0x593b9f8>`

Comment: I've added only the views to the project, and the controllers are in the gem folder. Also my edit.html.erb file is not inside the `devise/password/` directory, but I took it from there and added it to the `users/` directory. Any suggestions how to make it work

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems it working but have to do some extra work. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If an answer solves your problem you should mark it as “accepted” so that other users know that you're not still looking for an answer, and people with a similar problem know which answer to look at.

Comment: just getting an error, even if the form are ok it gives me this message `Current password new error message here` and form is not submitting as well

Comment: Sounds to me like the current password is incorrect, and the text `new error message here` is somewhere in your code?

Comment: @georgbrock: Exactly! and I removed the new error message here from my code. Now its works perfectly fine